# finding the cell value in every third data to plot a graph

Tags: excel, vba

I want to find the 3RD data in col A range. Col A range starts at A4. There is no error in my code, but it contains A4 value. I just want values from A7, A10, A13,... How do i do so? my data starts at A4

```
Sub mul()

Dim MyRange As Range
Dim RowSelect As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set MyRange = Range("A4:A" & lastRow)
Set RowSelect = MyRange.Rows(3)
For i = 4 To MyRange.Rows.Count Step 3
    Set RowSelect = Union(RowSelect, MyRange.Rows(i))
Next i
Application.Goto RowSelect

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't actually looping through all the rows, this does that and selects every 3rd row from A7 onwards.

```
Sub mul() 
Dim MyRange As Range 
Dim RowSelect As Range 
Dim i As Integer 
Dim lastRow As Long

    lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set MyRange = Range("A7:A" & lastRow)
    Set RowSelect = MyRange.Rows(1)
    For i = 7 To lastRow Step 3
        Set RowSelect = Union(RowSelect, Range("A" & i))
    Next i
    Application.Goto RowSelect

End Sub
```